# Kentico 9 and Publish button

Tags: c#, kentico

In visual studio 2015 for a Kentico 9 project I created a custom web part that is placed on the home page.  It has a Page_PreRender method and checks the date and time of the emergency page with the current date and time and if there is a difference in the time stamp and the difference in the time stamp is within a 24 hour period of the current time it makes an emergency icon flash until the 24 hour period ends or they go and update the emergency page by clicking on the Save buton again. I also have a counter to check how many times the Save button is clicked. The above data is queried from the database since the timestamps etc are saved when the Save button is clicked. In short one click, Saves the emergency page and the emergency icon starts to flash. If you click on the Save button again (for a 2nd time) it switches of the the Flashing of the Emergency Icon. This was necessary if the emergency page content was changed but there was not a real/immediate emergency that warrant a flashing emergency icon to make users aware.

The above worked when we did not have a workflow in place for Kentico. Since a workflow was added and there is a publish/reject buttons. Clicking on the Publish button makes the emergency icon to flash and you end up in a battle between the Save button and the Publish button. I can turn off the WorkFlow for the Emergency page but want to see if there is a way to check if the publish button was clicked.

**My question is how do I check which button was clicked in the Page_PreRender method using the Kentico buttons Save/Publish/Reject etc. in an if condition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of options here:

1. Configure automated publishing in workflow
2. Implement a separate workflow for this particular page, that does not require approval

To answer your question on how to check which button was clicked - check if document is currently published:

published would mean that Publish button has been clicked, otherwise - Save

Comment: Ok Thank you for replying. I will look at your 3rd option of checking if the page/document is in publish state. For option 1 I don't wish to have auto publishing and for 2 like I said I can (turn off/exclude) the workflow from the Emergency page but wanted to see if there was a way to check if the Publish button was clicked.

Comment: Thank you Roman. Used DocumentWorkflowStepID in the database to see if the document is in Save or Publish state.

Answer (score 0):

You can tie into the [publish event](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Reference+-+Global+system+events) to tell when the document is published:

```
 public class CustomWorkflowEventsAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        WorkflowEvents.Publish.Before += PublishDocument;
    }
```

Just a suggestion, maybe it would be easier to only have the icon flash based off the last published version of the document? Maybe have a field on the emergency document that is a bool to display or not display the flashing icon, if they want to disable it, just uncheck it and publish it.

Comment: Thank you Zach.  Tried to implement a 2nd button for the flashing. They did not agree. "Took up space" :-) Good suggestion to make the checking in the publish part but prefer it on the Save only because if they publish and within that publish moment see there is a mistake in the content the major version number will go one up when you try to save it again instead of the minor version number.